# Writing odd numbers to array in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write even numbers upto a limit into a list in Python using the following code

```
def odd_count(n):
    arr = list(50)
    for i in range(0,n,2):
        arr[i] = i
    return arr
```

I am gettting an error sayng `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. What is wrong in this code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Your title says you want odd numbers, your body says even. Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

This line raises the above mentioned exception

```
arr = list(50)
```

`list` expects an `iterable` object (something that has a `__iter__()` method). You are passing an `int` instead.

To create a list of size 50 you can use the `*` operator on a list:

```
arr = [None] * 50
```

This will create a list with all 50 elements set to `None`.

A more pythonic way to solve your problem is to pass the `range` object directly to the `list` constructor like:

```
def odd_count(n):
    return list(range(1,n+1, 2))

print(odd_count(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the list with brackets. In the for loop, use `.append()`. The final code should be

```
def odd_count(n):
    arr = []
    for i in range(0,n,2):
        arr.append(i)
    return arr
```

Comment: identation, sir

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: The question says odd in the title, even in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Python's list comprehension if you want to be Pythonic:

```
def even_numbers(n):
    return [i for i in range(0,n,2)]
```

Comment: No-op listcomps aren't really Pythonic; if it's the identity transform with no filter, you'd just do `list(range(0, n, 2))`, which is faster (for all but the smallest inputs), shorter, and equivalent.